# How to make mixed C/C++ project work using CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake, compiler-errors

I have a mixed C / C++ project which I can successfully compile and run using a Makefile (if it is needed please say so).
I would like to use CMake to build the project. My CMakeLists.txt looks as follows

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(project_name)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(include)

add_executable(main
        src/some_file.cpp
        src/other_file.c
        ... and so on
)
```

I basically have an include/ and src/ folder holding C and CPP source and header files respectively.

Now, in one file (utils.hpp) I include string and vector like .

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

When trying to build I get `fatal error: 'string' file not found` . 
I can instead to #include `<string.h>` which makes the error go away but then I get `fatal error: 'vector' file not found`. Very strange behaviour. I tried to setup a simple dummy project with the very simple code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec(3);
    std::cout << std::string("Hello, World!") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and most simple CMakeLists.txt adding just a target for this file otherwhise same as above and everything works just fine. So Is there an issue with the mixing of C/C++? What could cause those issues?

Compiler Info:

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

EDIT: Adding requested information.
Out put of `make VERBOSE=Y` on the generated Makefile from CMake.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.14.1/bin/cmake -S/Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode -B/Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode/cmakebuild --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.14.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode/cmakebuild/CMakeFiles /Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode/cmakebuild/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/benchmark.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/benchmark.dir/depend
cd /Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode/cmakebuild && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.14.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode /Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode /Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode/cmakebuild /Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode/cmakebuild /Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode/cmakebuild/CMakeFiles/benchmark.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/benchmark.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/benchmark.dir/build
[ 14%] Building C object CMakeFiles/benchmark.dir/src/hgwosca.c.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc  -I/Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode/include  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/benchmark.dir/src/hgwosca.c.o   -c /Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode/src/hgwosca.c
In file included from /Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode/src/hgwosca.c:14:
/Users/matthausheer/university/howtowritefastnumericalcode/fastcode/include/utils.hpp:3:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/benchmark.dir/src/hgwosca.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/benchmark.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(fastcode)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(include)

add_executable(benchmark
        src/benchmark.cpp
        src/hgwosca.c
        src/objectives.c
        src/penguin.c
        src/run_benchmark.cpp
        src/utils.cpp)
```

for the following files I have in my project.

[image]

Comment: You made sure that your C file has a `.c` extension and your C++ file has a `.cpp` extension, right?  You made sure not to include C++ headers like `string` and `vector` in a C file, or headers included by a C file, right?  Could you run `make VERBOSE=Y` and post the full output here so we can see how the compiler was invoked, what file it was invoked on, instead of just seeing the error message?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can instead to #include" ?

Comment: Please include the whole error message, so that we can see which file actually generated the error.

Comment: I can instead to #include: Sorry had to escape the brackets, I meant string.h. I added the requested information. Now looking at the ouput I assume the issue is that the C file hgwosca.c includes a CPP header utils.hpp. When I use my Makefile I actually use the g++ compiler to compile and link everything (also the C files) which gives me a funny message ```clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]```. However everything works there.